# How to add activity indicator on splash image

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7

I need to show activity indicator on splash image, i need to add view controller at the place of splash image or need to do something else??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this. In your root view controller, place the UIImageView with the splash image. In the DidLoad method of that view controller add the Activity Indicator programatically and set the timer for specific time using NSTimer (for example 10 sec), load the new view controller inside the method of Timer and invalidate the timer. Let me know if you need the code for this.

Answer (score 1):

you can't do it for splash screen if you want to do activity indicator after load splash show same image with help of imageview then display activity indicator in didfinishinglaunch mentod

Answer (score 1):

**You can not put the indicator view on a splash screen.** For that, you have to **create** a **viewcontroller** and you have to **put the splash image and indicator view in it**